# Browser checks if modified(result=304) when not needed

Tags: performance, http, browser, caching

I am trying to prevent If-modified request from client to server but I am failing.
I think that I am missing something so I am attaching the HTTP communication of the two requests. I would expect that the second request will not be issued:

```
GET XXXXX/js/Is.js HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Referer: http://XXXXX/XXXXX/
Accept-Language: he
UA-CPU: x86
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; Hewlett-Packard; .NET CLR 1.0.3705; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729)
Host: xxxxxxxx:8080
Connection: Keep-Alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cookie: JSESSIONID=XXXXXX



HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Pragma: No-cache
Cache-Control: public,max-age=860000
Expires: Sun, 3 Jan 2010 00:00:00 GMT
ETAG: W/"1634-1260925588406"
Last-Modified: Wed, 16 Dec 2009 01:06:28 GMT
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Type: text/javascript
Content-Length: 412
Date: Sun, 27 Dec 2009 07:25:52 GMT




GET /XXXXXXXX/Is.js HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Referer: http://XXXXXXXXX/XXXXXXX/servlet/Main
Accept-Language: he
UA-CPU: x86
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
If-Modified-Since: Wed, 16 Dec 2009 01:06:28 GMT
If-None-Match: W/"1634-1260925588406"
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; Hewlett-Packard; .NET CLR 1.0.3705; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729)
Host: xxxxxx:8080
Connection: Keep-Alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cookie: JSESSIONID=XXXXXX; 

HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Pragma: No-cache
Cache-Control: public,max-age=860000
Expires: Sun, 3 Jan 2010 00:00:00 GMT
ETAG: W/"1634-1260925588406"
Date: Sun, 27 Dec 2009 07:34:33 GMT
```

Comment: As other respondents have noted, the `Pragma: no-cache` in the *request* is causing the issue. So how is it getting there? One possibility is a META tag in the original HTML; another is a configuration in the browser. You've got the right idea, to look at the actual web traffic. Next step is to clear caches, restart both browser and server, and examine the "clean" traffic -- including the content of the HTML.

Comment: I cannot count then number of times I have restarted the server the client and cleaned the cache....  Do you think that the client request pragma:no-cache is originated by something in the referring HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that I have found the problem.... I knew that I was missing something
The first document loaded is doing redirect with :

```
 <meta HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" CONTENT="1; URL=/XXXXX">
```

Thanks for all your help ....

Answer (score 1):

The `Pragma: no-cache` in the second request indicates that it happened as a result of a page refresh.  A 304 is a correct response in that case. If you want to force a re-read, then you should use control-refresh.

Comment: Also, keep in mind that the Pragma: no-cache will be sent automatically if you're navigating to the target page by way of a META REFRESH.

Comment: I do not want to force reread quite the contrary. I was not issuing a page refresh. I was navigating to a blank page and then going back.

Comment: Can you eliminate the `Pragma` header from the response? Also, technically (according to the HTTP RFC), there's supposed to be a space between the comma in the Cache-Control header and the second field. It probably won't make a difference, but it might. It looks like you're using IE7. Is that correct? How were you navigating to the blank page and back? With an `<a>` tag and the browser's back button? Or with script? Or a redirect? Or a `<meta>` tag?

Comment: Thanks,
Yes I am using IE7 I was navigating to about:blank
and then I have navigated to the page back 
I will try to eliminate the pragma

Comment: Well it did not solve the problem, I don't get it.....
Maybe it is related somehow to the html?
First response header:
 
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 2020 02:00:00 IST
Cache-Control: public
Last-Modified: Sun, 27 Dec 2009 12:37:43 GMT
ETag: W/"1634-1261917463046"
Content-Type: text/javascript
Content-Length: 1634
Date: Mon, 28 Dec 2009 12:19:17 GMT

second request
HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 2020 02:00:00 IST
Cache-Control: public
Last-Modified: Sun, 27 Dec 2009 12:37:43 GMT
Date: Mon, 28 Dec 2009 12:20:10 GMT

Comment: "IST" as a time zone on Expires isn't legal; it should be GMT. Also, the max-age section of Cache-Control is now missing. Expires is actually semi-deprecated in favor of max-age for HTTP 1.1.

Comment: Thanks for all your help :-) I have changed it but still this awful 304 :-(... Am I missing something ? may it be related to the weak etag?
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Expires: 01 Jan 2020 02:00:00 GMT
Cache-Control: public,max-age=860000
Last-Modified: Sun, 27 Dec 2009 12:37:43 GMT
ETag: W/"1634-1261917463046"
Content-Type: text/javascript
Content-Length: 1634
Date: Mon, 28 Dec 2009 13:24:33 GMT

Comment: It looks like it must be related to the `Proxy: no-cache` in the request headers; that shouldn't be there for a "regular" request, such as from clicking on a link or hitting the Back button in the browser. The usual cause is either hitting the Refresh button in the browser, or a meta refresh tag on the page. IIRC, there are other meta tags on the page that can cause it, too (such as no-cache). Do you have any meta tags on the page?

Answer (score 0):

You're sending `Pragma: No-cache` in your first response. That [prevents Firefox](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=25&t=673135) from caching.

Comment: Thanks, I tried to change it to Pragma: cache but it did not help.
I do not understand why the browser is issuning a Pragma: no-cache on the request